# Something not right with AJAX code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page with a menu of categories and subcategories of products.
Categories have a class 'category' and subcategories have a class 'subcategory'. When either is clicked some AJAX sends the category to some php to compile the html which the AJAX then sends back to the page to populate a div. This part works fine.

There is a function in the code to split the returned records. So say there are 6 records and the page is to show 2 at a time then there are 3 pages. I get the correct amount of pages displayed(1 2 3) but all 6 records displayed on each!

Can anyone see the problem?

```
$('a.category, a.subcategory').click(function (e) {
    // first stop the link to go anywhere
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the class of the link
    var linkClass = $(this).attr("class");
    //get the text of the link by converting the clicked object to string
    var linkText = new String(this);
    // the value after the last / is the category ID
    var categoryValue = linkText.substring(linkText.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    // put the post parameters into 'params' to pass through the AJAX post request
    var params = {};
    params[linkClass] = categoryValue;
    // send the category ID to the getProductData.php script using jquery ajax post method
    // send along a category ID
    // on success insert the returned text into the chosen div
    $.post('../inc/showproducts.php', params, function (data) {
        //find total number of records
        var totalRecords = $(data).length;
        //define how many records shown per page
        var pageSize = 2
        //work out number of pages needed to hold records
        var numOfPages = Math.ceil(totalRecords / pageSize);
        //make page links
        var i,
        pageLinks = '<div class="pageLinks">';
        for (i = 0; i < numOfPages; i++) {
            pageLinks += '<a href="#" onclick="showProductPage(' + i + ');return false;">' + (i + 1) + '<\/a> ';
        }
        pageLinks += '<\/div>';
        //display returned data and page links in chosen div (.showproduct)
        $('.showproduct').html(pageLinks + data);
        showProductPage(0);
    });
});
//function to slice up records into pages
function showProductPage(pageNo) {
    var perPage = 2;
    var start = pageNo * perPage;
    var end = start + perPage;
    $('.image').hide().filter(function (index) {
        return ((index > (start - 1)) && (index < end));
    }).show();
}
```

Comment: FFS you don't need to document every single statement. It makes your code unreadable.

Comment: Its for school MightyPork, come on now, don't you know every college in the country is using Stack to do their homework for them now ;)

Comment: @Michelle sometimes a Professor (or Architect) will write a pseudo-code flow with comments and then expect the student (or Dev) to write working code to match the pseudo.  It looks a lot like that.  FWIW the OP did NOT ask for opinions about his commenting style.

Comment: thanks guys, its not for school. im in my 30's. But i do apologise for using so many comments to help me remember what what and maybe learn. Thanks for the -1 by the way. It must be great being you..............

Comment: I didn't give you a -minus 1. I attempted a solution for ya, not sure the javascript completely works but you get the idea, sorry for joking around on your account. But ya you are being very detailed with comments on such things as your var count declarations where it is obvious what is going on because of the names you are using for your variable declarations, for example "var numOfPages", great everyone knows exactly what it is, no need for additional comments ;).

Comment: I do appreciate your help Brian and I don't mind joking about at all!

Comment: I'm from Northern Ireland, we need a sense of humour to stay here! I still dont see the need for the -1 from someone. My question wasnt 'Do I have to many comments?'

Answer (score 0):

```
//check out this line of your code
    $('.showproduct').html(pageLinks + data);
```

The data var has all the records in it still. You have to get each data[position] with a for loop that iterates based on pageSize * pageNum. So page 1 would look like

```
var iterationSize = pageSize  * pageNum; //(2 * 1 = 2)
var i;
var j = 0;
var pageData[];
for(i = pageNum - 1; i < iterationSize; i++, j++){
    pageData[j] = data[i];
}

$('.showproduct').html(pageLinks + pageData.join(''));
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, Ill try this and see how I go!!

Comment: How do I get pageNum?

Comment: The pageNum is already being passed to your showProductPage() function, you are calling it"pageNo". Do you have a good understanding of this code, is this homework for you?

Comment: Its not homework Brian, I dont go to school/college etc. I'm doing myself a site and trying to learn a bit as i go. I dont really have a good understanding of the code, its stuff i picked up of the net really. I dont know where to put your code into mine, when i tried it, clicking on the links just resulted in the cat_id being used as the link.  'www.yoursite.com/4 does not exist on this server' I was obviously doing something wrong!!

Comment: I understand, ya my answer was written, assuming you had written the code yourself and would know were to integrate my suggest solution to see if it works, could you put the entire code on JsFiddle for me?

Comment: ill try, ive never used jsfiddle!

Comment: when you say the entire code, dos that include the html and css?

Comment: I'm kind of lost. Theres one html box, but i have 2 php files to output html, the menu and the showproducts file that the ajax gets its data from!